# Trigger to update only if value is in lookup table

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2017, ddl-trigger

I only want to update the comment if a description for the event is found in the TagDescLookup Table.  If the Tag isn’t in the Lookup table then don’t change the existing Value for the comment column.  The current trigger will update the comment column with the correct value unless the value isn't found in the lookup table, it sets comment to Null.  I'm using SQL server 2017.

```
USE [AwxLogger]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TagDescTrigger]    Script Date: 14/03/2019 16:47:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TagDescTrigger]
    ON [dbo].[EventLog]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
       BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON
              UPDATE [dbo].[EventLog]
        SET Comment =
                  (
            SELECT [Description] FROM TagDescLookup
            WHERE Tag = I.NameOfParameter
            )
        FROM [dbo].[EventLog] AS E
        JOIN INSERTED AS I
              ON E.NameOfParameter = I.NameOfParameter
       END
```

`TagDescLookup` Table

```
ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1)  
Tag nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL  
Description nvarchar(MAX)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a foreign key, without any triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the a second where condition (WHERE E.ConditionName NOT like '%log%') to exclude the items I didn't want updated.  Tested and works well so far... Thanks for the other suggestions and help

```
        (
        SELECT [Description] FROM TagDescLookup
        WHERE Tag = I.NameOfParameter AND Description IS NOT NULL 
        )
    FROM [dbo].[EventLog] AS E
    JOIN INSERTED AS I  
    ON E.NameOfParameter = I.NameOfParameter WHERE E.ConditionName NOT like '%log%' 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the trigger to only update when the `NameOfParameter` matches the `Tag` from `TagDescLookup`

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TagDescTrigger]
    ON [dbo].[EventLog]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
       BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON

        UPDATE E
        SET E.Comment =TDL.[Description]
        FROM
        [dbo].[EventLog] AS E
        JOIN INSERTED AS I
        ON E.NameOfParameter = I.NameOfParameter
        JOIN TagDescLookup AS TDL
        ON TDL.Tag = I.NameOfParameter;
        END
    END
```

You really need to look out for duplicate `Tag`'s.

---

**Testing**

```
CREATE TABLE  TagDescLookup 
(ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1)  ,
 Tag nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL  ,
 Description nvarchar(MAX)  );

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog]
(Comment  nvarchar(MAX),
NameOfParameter nvarchar(max));
```

**Example1**

```
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventLog](Comment,NameOfParameter)
  VALUES('bla','bla');

  select * from dbo.EventLog;
```

**Result1**

```
Comment NameOfParameter
bla bla
```

**Example2**

```
  Insert into TagDescLookup(Tag,Description) 
  VALUES('TaggedVal','NewDescription');


  INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventLog](Comment,NameOfParameter)
  VALUES('OldDescription?','TaggedVal');


  SELECT * From dbo.EventLog;
```

**Result2**

```
Comment NameOfParameter
bla bla
NewDescription  TaggedVal
```

Comment: There won't be any duplicates in the lookup table as it is manually created at the start and won't be updated. I tried using the suggested code but it still overwrites the original data in the comment field even if no matching tag is found in the lookup table. It sets the comment Value to Null instead of leaving the original value. The purpose of the TagDescLookup table is to change the comment value in the eventlog to a more descriptive value. Not all events will need to be changed, only values in the lookup table